# Qt - Update issue to Sqlite using multiple query

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, qt

I'm trying to update a row in a SQlite DB through QT and my query doesn't execute even though I tested it in my db manager where it works so I'm confused.

You'll find the code below :

```
void DataBase::automatisationQteStock(Liste_Commande listeCommande){

if(db.isOpen()){

    QSqlQuery query;

    QSqlQuery query2;
    
    QString querySelectIdCompo = "select Id_Composition from Carte_composition cc where Id_Carte  = :idcarte ;";

    QString queryUpdate = "update Stock set quantite = quantite - dose from (select quantite as dose, Id_Stock from Composition where Id_Composition = :tmp) where Stock.Id_Stock = (select Id_Stock from Composition where Id_Composition = :tmp);";

    query.prepare(querySelectIdCompo);

    query.bindValue(":idcarte", listeCommande.getId_Carte());

    query.exec();

    while(query.next()){

        qint8 tmp = query.value("Id_Composition").toInt();

        qDebug() << tmp;

        query2.prepare(queryUpdate);

        query2.bindValue(":tmp",tmp);

        query2.exec();

        qDebug() << "Transaction reussie";
    }
}

else
{
    qDebug() << "Connexion avec la database n'est pas établie";
}
```

}

Comment: The `UPDATE...FROM` syntax is supported by SQLite since version 3.33.0. Probably you are using an older version. Execute `select sqlite_version();` to verify.

Comment: 3.34 .0 is the one of my DB

Comment: It doesn't prepare query2 in the loop, that's the issue but I don't understand why

Comment: Post sample data of both tables and expected results to clarify what you want. I'm sure this can be done with a simple UPDATE statement without the need of a SELECT query and a WHILE loop.

Comment: I fixed it, the issue was the multiple statements in my update which is not supported ; I splitted  the main update query in 3 subsequents and it worked like a charm

Comment: update Stock 
set quantite = ( select quantite - dose from Composition where Id_Composition = :tmp and Stock.Id_Composition=Id_Composition)